# Fix ChartJS Values not Well Displayed

Tags: chart.js

How to make ChartJS scale a little more than the highest value to correctly display the value above the highest bar?

[image]

Here the second value (14) is half displayed and the third one (15) is not even displayed.

Here is the code:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('chart-hour');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['09h - 10h', '10h - 11h', '11h - 12h', '12h - 13h', '13h - 14h', 'PAUSE DEJ', '15h - 16h', '16h - 17h', '17h - 18h'],
        datasets: [{
            label: '',
            data: [0,14,15,7,1,0,0,0,0],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        legend: {
            display: false
        },
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

And the plugin used to display the values:

```
Chart.plugins.register({
    afterDatasetsDraw: function(chart) {
        var ctx = chart.ctx;

        chart.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset, i) {
            var meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(i);
            if (!meta.hidden) {
                meta.data.forEach(function(element, index) {
                    // Draw the text in black, with the specified font
                    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(20, 20, 20)';

                    var fontSize = 15;
                    var fontStyle = 'normal';
                    var fontFamily = 'Montserrat';
                    ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(fontSize, fontStyle, fontFamily);

                    // Just naively convert to string for now
                    var dataString = dataset.data[index].toString();

                    // Make sure alignment settings are correct
                    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
                    ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';

                    var padding = 0;
                    var position = element.tooltipPosition();
                    ctx.fillText(dataString, position.x, position.y - (fontSize / 2) - padding);
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a way to do it:

Put the values in an array and get the highest value.

Then if the highest value is 0, set `max: 10` in yAxes

If the highest value is greater than 0, then add 10 to the highest value, put it in a variable then pass it to `max:`